# Hanging self referencing list in Haskell to compute primes list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I recently started learning Haskell. To train a bit I wanted to try generating the list of prime numbers via self reference using the following code:

```hs
main = do
    print (smaller_than_sqrt 4 2)
    print (smaller_than_sqrt_list 5 [2..])
    print ("5")
    print (is_prime 5 [2..])
    print ("7")
    print (is_prime 7 [2..])
    print ("9")
    print (is_prime 9 [2..])
    print ("test")
    print (take 5 primes) -- Hangs

-- Integer square root
isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt = ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral

-- Checks if x is smaller than sqrt(p)
smaller_than_sqrt :: Int -> Int -> Bool
smaller_than_sqrt p x = x <= isqrt p

-- Checks if x doesn't divide p
not_divides :: Int -> Int -> Bool
not_divides p x = p `mod` x /= 0

-- Takes in a number and an ordered list of numbers and only keeps the one smaller than sqrt(p)
smaller_than_sqrt_list :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
smaller_than_sqrt_list p xs = takeWhile (smaller_than_sqrt p) xs

-- Checks if p is prime by looking at the provided list of numbers and checking that none divides p
is_prime :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
is_prime p xs = all (not_divides p) (smaller_than_sqrt_list p xs)

-- Works fine: primes = 2 : [ p | p <- [3..], is_prime p [2..]]
-- Doesn't work:
primes = 2 : 3 : [ p | p <- [5..], is_prime p primes]
```

But for some reason referencing `primes` inside of `primes` hangs when running `runhaskell` and is detected as a loop error when running the compiled binary with `ghc`.

However I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, the first two elements of `primes` are 2 and 3. What comes after that? The next element of `primes` is the first element of

```
[p | p <- [5..], is_prime p primes]
```

What's that? It could be 5, if `is_prime 5 primes`, or it could be some larger number. To find out which, we need to evaluate

```
smaller_than_sqrt_list 5 primes
```

Which requires

```
takeWhile (<= isqrt 5) primes
```

Which requires

```
takeWhile (<= 3) primes
```

Well, that's easy enough, it starts with `2:3:...`, right? Okay, but what's the next element? We need to look at the third element of `primes` and see whether it's less or equal to 3. But the third element of `primes` is what we were trying to calculate to begin with!

Comment: Doesn't `\p x -> x <= isqrt p` mean `\p -> \x -> x <= isqrt p`, not `\p -> let sr = isqrt p in \x -> x <= sr`? I.e. I don't think the `isqrt p` computation is shared

Comment: Yes, it's not a perfectly faithful simplification. But it's shorter to write and is guaranteed to produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `smaller_than_sqrt 5 3` is still `True`. To compute whether `5` is a prime, the `is_prime 5 primes` expands to `all (not_divides 5) (takeWhile (smaller_than_sqrt 5) primes)`, and `takeWhile` will attempt to iterate `primes` until the predicate no longer holds. It does hold for the first element (`2`), it still does hold for the second element (`3`), will it hold for the next element - wait what's the next element? We're still computing which one that is!

It should be sufficient to use `floor` instead of `ceiling` in `isqrt`, or simpler just

```
smaller_than_sqrt p x = x * x <= p
```